# Como paso una fecha a un input con asp net core mvc

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Estoy haciendo una web para un API que ya esta hecho. El API no esta hecho con EF sino con métodos propios. En el EDIT controller tengo lo siguiente:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id)
        {
            var action = await controller.GetMobileDocumentoFormato(id);

            OkObjectResult okResult = action.Result as OkObjectResult;

            ViewBag.aplicaciones = okResult.Value;

            return View();
        }
```

Lo cual carga todos los datos en la vista correctamente excepto la fecha.
El código de la vista es este:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UltimaActualizacion" class="control-label"></label>
                 <span>
                    <span style="color: Mediumslateblue;">
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input asp-for="UltimaActualizacion" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.aplicaciones.UltimaActualizacion" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UltimaActualizacion" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Todos los otros inputs me cargan los datos bien solo la fecha no la carga . Como puedo arreglarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A que te refieres no se ve o que es lo que pasa?

Comment: Me refiero a que no trae el dato y lo pone en el input :

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Observe la imagen

Comment: Me ah pasado y lo dejo de lado de js para evitar esas complicaciones

Comment: podrias mostrarnos el formato (la cadena de texto) que viene en @ViewBag.aplicaciones.UltimaActualizacion?

Answer (score 0):

El problema podría ser que estas insertando en el input un patron de fecha incorrecto, generalmente el input de tipo datetime require un patron ISO similar a YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM y en caso de que no pueda convertir el valor subministrado por el modelo simplemente no se muestra nada.

```
ViewBag.aplicaciones.UltimaActualizacion = DateTime.ParseExact(ViewBag.aplicaciones.UltimaActualizacion, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Se ve esta forma cuando entro a Details o al Index Vea la última imagen que agregue

Comment: ese podría ser el problema el input es incapaz de convertir tu formato al formato requerido, intenta con la actualización de mi respuesta.

Comment: Si le pongo al Input type="datetime" ahí si me   muestra la fecha pero se desaparece el botón que permite cambiar la fecha !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando de la vista esta línea:

```
<input asp-for="UltimaActualizacion" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.aplicaciones.UltimaActualizacion" />
```

por esta otra:

```
<input asp-for="UltimaActualizacion" class="form-control" value="@(ViewBag.aplicaciones.UltimaActualizacion.ToString("g", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES"))))" />
```

**Nota:** 
Como recomendación no deberías usar ViewBag si no un modelo, es decir, crearte por ejemplo esta clase:

```
public class DetailModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:g}")]
    public DateTime LastUpdate{ get; set; }

    public DetailModel(DateTime lastUpdate){ 
        LastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }
}
```

Luego en tu Controlador

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id)
{
    var action = await controller.GetMobileDocumentoFormato(id);

    OkObjectResult okResult = action.Result as OkObjectResult;

    DetailModel datailModel = new DetailModel(okResult.Value);

    return View(datailModel);
}
```

y finalmente la vista:

```
<input asp-for="UltimaActualizacion" class="form-control" value="@Model.LastUpdate" />
```

Comment: Esto no funcionó y el modelo no lo puedo modificar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas seguro es que ya resolviste pero dejo esta respuesta para alguien que en el futuro busque algo mira yo tuve el mismo problema, se debe a que el navegador regresa el formato de la fecha como el lo obtiene del cliente por lo tanto todo se soluciona simplemente con no definirle formato en el modelo

```
//[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]          
[Required, Display(Name = "Fecha", Description = "Fecha", Prompt = "Fecha")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime fechadoc { get; set; }
```

si quieres darle una fecha inicial basta que lo mandes desde el controller asi:

```
      [HttpGet]
      public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
      {
           ViewBag.Title = "Agregar Factura";
           ViewBag.ListaProv = new SelectList(await _iProvApp.Listar(), "proveedorID", "proveedorname");
           ViewBag.ListaSoc = new SelectList(await _iSoc.Listar(), "sociedadID", "sociedad");
           ViewBag.ListaImp = new SelectList(await _iImp.Listar(), "impID", "descripcion");
           ViewBag.ListaImpPor = new SelectList(await _iImp.Listar(), "impID", "porcentaje");

           return View(new CargoModel
           {
                fechadoc = DateTime.Now,
                fechaven = DateTime.Now,
                prenta = 6
           });
      }
```

a mi me va bien veo la fecha en el formato que el cliente define en su equipo y no tengo problema para guardarla y presentarla espero les sirva